# If $a.b (a+b )=2000$ What is the value of $\frac {1}{a}+\frac {1}{b}+\frac {1}{a+b}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a\times b(a+b )=2000$  What is the value of
$$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{a+b}$$

By trial and error, I get the $a=10$,$b=10$ and so the answer should be  $1/4$ , but is there any algebraic way to solve it?

Comment: `I get the a=10, b=10` If you assume $a,b$ to be positive integers, then you should write that into the question. Otherwise, that's not the only solution, even in integers.

Comment: Is there anything else mentioned in the question?

Comment: @XcoderX Don't think `b=0` works. But $a=10, b=-20$ does, for example.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I was mistaken.  As you have pointed out correctly, there is more than 1 set of solutions

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{a+b} = \frac{b(a+b) + a(a+b) + ab}{ab(a+b)}$.

I shall elaborate further.  We can change the fraction into $\frac{(a+b)^2}{2000}+\frac{1}{a+b}$.

Note that since $ab(a+b)=2000$, $(a+b)=\frac{2000}{ab}$.  We now substitute this into the above equation, getting $\frac{2000}{a^2b^2}+\frac{ab}{2000}$.  This does not seem factorisable to me.  Here, $a=10$ would definitely yield $\frac{1}{4}$, but the question is poorly defined with no single solution.

Comment: @user373141 what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

If we solve $ab^2+a^2b-2000=0$ for $b$ we obtain 
\begin{equation}
b=\frac{-a^2\pm\sqrt{a(a^3+20^3)}}{2a}
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
a+b=\frac{a^2\pm\sqrt{a(a^3+20^3)}}{2a}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{a+b}=\frac{2a}{a^2\pm\sqrt{a(a^3+20^3)}}
\end{equation}
which,  when rationalized gives
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{a+b}=\frac{2(-a^2\pm\sqrt{a(a^3+20^3)}}{20^3}
\end{equation}
By similiar steps you will find that
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{b}=\frac{2(a^2\pm\sqrt{a(a^3+20^3)}}{20^3}
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{a+b}=\frac{1}{a}\pm \frac{4\sqrt{a(a^3+20^3)}}{20^3}
\end{equation}
If we let $a=10$ and use the positive branch the sum resolves to $\frac{1}{4}$, but for other values of $a$ one obtains different results for the sum.